# AngularJS binding issues and iteration loops

Tags: angularjs

I have this factory:

```
.factory('Options', function () {
    var getOptions = function () {
        var storageData = sessionStorage.siteOptions;

        if (storageData !== 'undefined')
            return angular.fromJson(storageData);

        return {
            rotateBackground: false,
            enableMetro: true
        };
    };

    var saveOptions = function (options) {
        sessionStorage.siteOptions = angular.toJson(options);
    }

    return {
        get: getOptions,
        save: saveOptions
    };
});
```

which works fine on my profile page:

```
.controller('ProfileController', ['Options', function (options) {
    var self = this;

    self.options = options.get();
    self.save = function () {
        options.save(self.options);
    }
}]);
```

The html looks like this:

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="ProfileController as profile">
    <div class="large-4 columns">
        <h2>Site options</h2>

        <form name="optionsForm" ng-submit="profile.save()" role="form">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="large-12 columns">
                    <input id="enable-metro" type="checkbox" ng-model="profile.options.enableMetro"><label for="enable-metro">Enable metro design</label>
                </div>
                <div class="large-12 columns">
                    <input id="enable-background-rotate" type="checkbox" ng-model="profile.options.rotateBackground"><label for="enable-background-rotate">Enable rotating background</label>
                </div>
                <div class="large-12 columns">
                    <button class="button">Save</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

But I have this other page that has a controller that needs to be aware if the options are ever saved. Basically, if **saveOptions** is ever called, then I need any page that looks at options to be notified.
The reason for this, is for example:

```
.controller('MetroController', ['Options', function (options) {
    scope.options = options.get();

    scope.$watch(function () {
        return options.get();
    }, function () {
        scope.options = options.get();
    });
}])

// ---
// DIRECTIVES.
// ---

.directive('metro', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        controller: 'MetroController',
        controllerAs: 'metro',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            scope.$watch(function () {
                return metro.options.enableMetro;
            }, function (enableMetro) {
                if (enableMetro) {
                    element.addClass('metro');
                } else {
                    element.removeClass('metro');
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

As you can see, this is trying to apply a class based on the **enableMetro** flag. But when I run this, I get an error about the amount of iterations this has had to loop through. 
Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have this solved. 
I changed my options factory to this:

```
.factory('Options', function () {
    var getOptions = function () {
        var storageData = sessionStorage.siteOptions;

        if (storageData !== 'undefined')
            return angular.fromJson(storageData);

        return {
            rotateBackground: false,
            enableMetro: true
        };
    };

    var saveOptions = function (options) {
        sessionStorage.siteOptions = angular.toJson(options);

        current = getOptions();
    }

    var current = getOptions();

    return {
        current: current,
        save: saveOptions
    };
});
```

then in my controllers, I just did this:

```
.controller('MetroController', ['$scope', 'Options', function ($scope, options) {
    var self = this;

    self.options = options.current;

    $scope.$watch(function () {
        return options.current;
    }, function () {
        self.options = options.current;
    });
}])

// ---
// DIRECTIVES.
// ---

.directive('metro', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        controller: 'MetroController',
        link: function (scope, element, attr, controller) {
            scope.$watch(function () {
                return controller.options.enableMetro;
            }, function (enableMetro) {
                if (enableMetro) {
                    element.addClass('metro');
                } else {
                    element.removeClass('metro');
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

and that seems to work fine.